# Euler's Method with changing acceleration

Tags: differential-equations

The goal is basically to create a plot of both altitude and velocity vs time .
Given equations are:
d^2y/dt^2=-g-b*v
P(y)=P(0)*e^(-ky)

This is that I've attempted so far:

```
k = 1.256*10^-4;
b = 0.3266;
g = 9.8;
e = 2.71828;
inc = 0.1;
t[0] = 0;
v[0] = 0;
y[0] = 0;
P[0] = 17696;
P[y] = P[0]*e^(-k*y[t]);
y[t] = -g*y[t]*-b*y[t]*0.5*y^2;
v[t] = -g*v[t]*-b*v[t]*y[t];
a[t] = -g*-b*v[t];

i = 0;

While[
  y[i] > 0,
  P[i + 1] = P[0]*e^(-k*y[i]);
  t[i + 1] = t[i] + inc;
  y[i + 1] = v[i]*inc + y[i];
  v[i + 1] = a[i]*inc + v[i];
  a[i + 1] = -g*-b*v[i];
  i++
  ];
ptsvt = Table[{t[j], v[j]}, {j, 0, i}];
ptspt = Table[{t[j], P[j]}, {j, 0, i}];
ListLinePlot[ptsvt]
ListLinePlot[ptspt]
```

I'm pretty sure the main mistake is in the definition of y[t] and v[t]. I've tried several different equations and nothing seems to work. I'm not even sure if defining y[t] and v[t] is the right way to do it but I can't think of any other way.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You set `y[0]=0` and `i=0` and then `While[y[i]>0...` So think a minute. What does that mean happens with your `While` loop? Think carefully about those three things. Maybe you could put a `Print` before and another one inside your `While` and another one after it is done to show you what is happening at each step.

Comment: Do you need to use a While method? Or could you use NDSolve[] ?

Comment: While is required

Comment: Maybe you wanted to define `a[0] = -g - b*v[0];` and `a[i + 1] = -g - b*v[i];` (i.g., gravity `g` and magnetic accelertion b*v[i] of charged particle? Otherwise, acceleration, velocity, and position remain `0` all the time.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think you intend to declare y[t] implicitly:

```
y[t] = -g*y[t]*-b*y[t]*0.5*y^2;
```

I think this should rather read:

```
y[t_] = -g*y[t]*-b*y[t]*0.5*y^2;
```

Then by specifying:

```
y[0] = 0;
```

and in the while loop:

y[i + 1] = v[i]*inc + y[i];

y would never change. So I change this to `y[0]=1;` This is certainly not right together with `P[0] = 17696;` but at least it gets you going. Change the other initial conditions according to your problem. These changes together with the correction from Henrik (`a[0] = -g - b*v[0];`):

```
Clear[t, y, v, P, a];
k = 1.256*10^-4;
b = 0.3266;
g = 9.8;
e = 2.71828;
inc = 0.1;
t[0] = 0;
v[0] = 0;
y[0] = 1;
P[0] = 17696;
a[0] = -g - b*v[0];
P[y_] := P[0]*e^(-k*y[t]);
y[t_] := -g*y[t]*-b*y[t]*0.5*y^2;
v[t_] := -g*v[t]*-b*v[t]*y[t];
a[t_] := -g*-b*v[t];

i = 0; inc = .01;

While[y[i] > 0,
  P[i + 1] = P[0]*e^(-k*y[i]);
  t[i + 1] = t[i] + inc;
  y[i + 1] = v[i]*inc + y[i];
  v[i + 1] = a[i]*inc + v[i];
  a[i + 1] = -g*-b*v[i];
  i++];
ptsvt = Table[{t[j], v[j]}, {j, 0, i}];
ptspt = Table[{t[j], P[j]}, {j, 0, i}];
ListLinePlot[ptsvt]
ListLinePlot[ptspt]
```

[image]

Now you can try to adapt the initial conditions or if you do not succeed, explain your problem.